# Does Dapper construct a new object for duplicated join results?

Tags: c#, dapper

When Dapper does a `JOIN` does it call the constructor for each `a`, `b`, `c`? or each unique `a`,`b`, `c`?

```
string sql = @"SELECT a.*, b.*, c.* 
               FROM A a
               JOIN B b ON b.Id = a.BId
               JOIN C c ON b.Id = c.BId";

var results = db.Query<A, B, C, A>(sql, (a, b, c) => { return a; });
```

For instance, if I have duplicates of `c`, will Dapper call `c`'s constructor many times?

Or will it notice the Ids are the same between the rows and pass me the same object for all instances where the id is the same?

**Edit:**

After some testing, it looks like it does call the constructor multiple times for duplicate values.

Is there a simple way to work around this using the Dapper API?

Comment: Just add `DISTINCT` in your query

Comment: I've rephrased the question. For clarity, I'm not looking for distinct rows, but distinct parts of the row, which Dapper returns with its `Query<TFirst, TSecond, ..., TReturn>()` method.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to propose my solution but leave this question open in case someone has a better idea.

This is what I've done:

```
List<dynamic> results = db.Query<dynamic, dynamic, dynamic, dynamic>(sql,
    (a, b, c) => { return new { a, b, c }; }).ToList(); // splitOn: 'Id'

List<dynamic> a_ids = new List<dynamic>();
List<dynamic> b_ids = new List<dynamic>();
List<dynamic> c_ids = new List<dynamic>();

List<A> unique_as = new List<A>();
List<B> unique_bs = new List<B>();
List<C> unique_cs = new List<C>();
foreach (var row in results)
{
    var a = row.a;
    var b = row.b;
    var c = row.c;
    if(!a_ids.Contains(a.Id)) unique_as.Add(new A(a.Id));
    if(!b_ids.Contains(b.Id)) unique_bs.Add(new B(b.Id));
    if(!c_ids.Contains(c.Id)) unique_cs.Add(new C(c.Id));
}
```

It would be nice if Dapper supported this in the future somehow, but until then, I hope this helps somebody else.

Comment: Why *should* Dapper eliminate duplicate rows when you don't provide the `DISTINCT` keyword in your query? It's contrary to what everyone expects when executing a SQL statement.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Because the row is distinct, but maybe part of the row (`a`, `b`, or `c`) is not distinct. `results[0].a.Id == results[1].a.Id` does not mean `results[0].c.Id == results[1].c.Id`

Comment: Then the SQL statement is wrong. It should specify *only* the columns that are actually need. Using `*` without reason is the source of a lot of bugs and bad performance in SQL. Not only does it pull a lot more data, it may result in an inefficient query because the server has to check more indexes or go directly to the table when it could find the required data in an index